# Find and FindNext to copy data corresponding to all matches

Tags: vba, excel

I want to search Column 5 on sheet "BD" for all the entries that match a value called "alocacao" on my sheet "Plan1".
Then copy the value on Column 2 to the cell called "tecnico1" (the other cells are called "tecnico2, tecnico3 and tecnico4").

[image]

The cell with the value TESTE 2 is the "alocacao".
[image]

[image]

I tried Find and FindNext:

```vb
Sub VerifProd_Click()
    
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim FirstAddr As String
    Dim fnd As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    i = 2
    fnd = Sheets(1).Range("alocacao").Value
    
    With Sheets("BD").Columns(5)
        Set LastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With
    
    Set FoundCell = Sheets("BD").Columns(5).Find(what:=fnd, after:=LastCell)
    
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddr = FoundCell.Address
    End If
    
    Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
        Sheets("BD").Cells(i,2).Copy Sheets("Plan1").Range("tecnico" & i).Value
        i = i + 1
        Set FoundCell = Sheets("BD").Columns(5).FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
        If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

I get

> Run-time error 1004

but the code is not highlighted.

**EDIT**

I changed a part of it to test if it will paste the value on cell B26.

Now I get

> Run-time error 438

```vb
With Sheets("BD").Columns(5)
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
End With
    
Set FoundCell = Sheets("BD").Columns(5).Find(what:=fnd, after:=LastCell)
    
If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    FirstAddr = FoundCell.Address
End If
    
Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
    Sheets("Plan1").Range("B26") = FoundCell.Adress.Offset(0, -3).Value
        
    Set FoundCell = Sheets("BD").Columns(5).FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
    If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: `FoundCell.Adress.Offset(0, -3).Value` remove the `.Address`

Comment: @A.S.H thanks. The funny thing is that now it's copying the value but it's getting the last match instead of the first...

Comment: Normal, because you're copying all the matches in the same place ;)

Comment: I suspect the `Range("tecnico" & i).Value`... I suppose your ranges are named `tecnico1, tecnico2 and tecnico3`? But what if there are more matches than 3?

Comment: @A.S.H yes! I thought about that then I changed to `Sheets("Plan1").Range("B26:B29") = FoundCell.Offset(0, -3).Value` and it's copying the last value in all range.

Comment: @A.S.H actually, the value `alocacao` can be associated with 4 `tecnicos` ranges, so that's the max number of match you can get... I made it like this for a reason.

Comment: @A.S.H I see... Anwyay these are my range names, actually.

Comment: ok see my suggestion below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok supposing you have 4 named cells in sheet `"Plan1"` with names `tecnico1, tecnico2, tecnico3 and tecnico4`, I suggest the following modification, having in mind that we should stop at `4` matches which the number of named ranges `tecnico`:

```
Sub VerifProd_Click()
    Dim FoundCell As Range, FirstAddr As String, fnd As String, i As Long

    fnd = Sheets(1).Range("alocacao").value
    Set FoundCell = Sheets("BD").Columns(5).Find(what:=fnd, _
        After:=Sheets("BD").Cells(Rows.count, 5), Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
 
    If FoundCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    FirstAddr = FoundCell.Adress
    Do
        i = i + 1
        Sheets("Plan1").Range("tecnico" & i).value = FoundCell.Offset(,-3).Value2
        Set FoundCell = Sheets("BD").Columns(5).FindNext(After:=FoundCell)
    Loop Until FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Or i >= 4
End Sub
```

Comment: I totally understood what you did there but I also got a run-time error 1004.

Comment: @paulinhax at which line? I suspect the named ranges were not found. I mean the ranges `tecnico1, tecnico2, tecnico3 and tecnico4` (or they are locked?)

Comment: I guess you're right, it gives me error when it reaches `Sheets("Plan1").Range("tecnico" & i).Value = FoundCell.Offset(-3).Value`. They're not locked, but they're merged cells... I don't know if it influences something, but I checked the named ranges and it exists.

Comment: What do you get if you type this in the immediate window?...................... `?Sheets("Plan1").Range("tecnico1").address` .. repeat it for `tecnico2` to 4.

Comment: It gives me the right addresses that are C10, C12, C14 and C16. I also checked my `alocacao` range and its correct too.

Comment: @paulinhax I forgot a comma in the `offset` statement. Should be `FoundCell.Offset(,-3)` with a comma to offset by columns. Corrected, please try it again.

Comment: I missed this too. Now it's correct and working! Thanks a lot for your patience :)

Comment: @paulinhax glad to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

.Find and .FindNext algorithm is used like below...

```
With Sheets("BD").Columns(5)
    Set FoundCell = .Find(what:=fnd, after:=LastCell)

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddr = FoundCell.Address
        Do
            Sheets("BD").Cells(i, 2).Copy Sheets("Plan1").Range("tecnico" & i).Value
            i = i + 1
            Set FoundCell = .FindNext(FoundCell)
        Loop While Not FoundCell Is Nothing And FirstAddr <> FoundCell.Address
    End If
End With
```