# vba issue with error handling

Tags: vba, excel

All the informations about the my sheets are explained [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45287937/6088173). But I'll explain it quickly:

I have 3 sheets (`Plan1, BANCO and DB`). `Plan1` has named ranges where I insert information and this information is stored on `BANCO` and copied to `BD` (this last one saves all past informations while `BANCO` only has last information inserted).

I also have a code to verify if the named range `alocacao` already exists on `BD` and if it exists, they're load again on `Plan1`. After this, you can change the name of `alocacao` after inserting the new name in a range named `substituit_aloc` using the code below:

```
Sub SubstituirProduto_Click()
Dim FoundCell As Range, FirstAddr As String, fnd As String, newAloc As Range, i As Long

On Error GoTo Catch

    fnd = Sheets("Plan1").Range("alocacao").Value
    Set newAloc = Sheets("Plan1").Range("substituir_aloc")

    Set FoundCell = Sheets("BD").Columns(5).Find(what:=fnd, _
        After:=Sheets("BD").Cells(Rows.Count, 5), Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddr = FoundCell.Address
    End If

    Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
        i = i + 1
        FoundCell.Value = newAloc.Value

        Set FoundCell = Sheets("BD").Columns(5).FindNext(After:=FoundCell)
        If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Or i >= 30 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

Catch:
MsgBox "Substituido!"

End Sub
```

Sometimes it works and sometimes it gets:

> Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

And highlithed line:

```
If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Or i >= 30 Then
```

Despite the error, it does what it need to without influencing the  end result. Thus I added the `On Error GoTo Catch` just to doesn't show the error message and finishs to run the code, but I'm still getting the error message.

Someone know why it is still showing the error message without being catched by my error handling?

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the very top of your module and then compile.

Comment: @braX I already did that and get the same thing. The problem is that sometimes it works fine but sometimes it still get the error without a reason (at least for me).

Comment: @braX without the error handling the error occurs on line `If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Or i >= 30 Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
  If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Or i >= 30 Then
     Exit Do
  End If
End If
```

Comment: why `If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then` instead of `If FoundCell Is Nothing Then`?

Comment: Because it if is `Nothing` it will not have an `Address` property to read.

Answer (score 0):

In the code below the FoundCell might be set to nothing (if the findnext returns nothing) before the address is tested, this'll give an error.

```
    Set FoundCell = Sheets("BD").Columns(5).FindNext(After:=FoundCell)
    If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Or i >= 30 Then
        Exit Do
    End If
```

A test to see if FoundCell is nothing before the address-test might solve this:

```
Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
    i = i + 1
    FoundCell.Value = newAloc.Value

    Set FoundCell = Sheets("BD").Columns(5).FindNext(After:=FoundCell)
    If FoundCell is nothing then Exit Do
    If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Or i >= 30 Then Exit Do
Loop
```